# Can't scroll a UISearchBar into view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

Suddenly I couldn't scroll up to my search bar because it kept being pulled under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by unchecking "hide bars when vertically compact" on the navigation controller.